# Euler's formula question

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers, exponential-function

I saw this formula in my book:

$$2i \sin(w)=e^{iw}-e^{-iw}$$

but I don't understand why this is true? isn't $\,\sin(w)=\frac{e^{iw}-e^{-iw}}{2}$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. It's$$\sin(w)=\frac{e^{iw}-e^{-iw}}{2i}.\tag1$$Therefore, that formula from your book is correct.

If you want to know *why* we have $(1)$, note that$$e^w=1+\frac w1+\frac{w^2}{2!}+\frac{w^3}{3!}+\cdots$$So,$$e^{iw}=1+i\frac w1-\frac{w^2}{2!}-i\frac{w^3}{3!}+\cdots$$and$$e^{-iw}=1-i\frac w1-\frac{w^2}{2!}+i\frac{w^3}{3!}+\cdots$$and so\begin{align}e^{iw}-e^{-iw}&=2i\left(\frac w1-\frac{w^3}{3!}+\frac{w^5}{5!}-\cdots\right)\\&=2i\sin(w).\end{align}

Comment: Very nice explanation.

Comment: @Sebastiano Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

If you're not sure you can do the proof:
We know that : $e^{iw} =\cos{w} +i\sin{w}$ and $e^{-iw} =\cos{w} -i\sin{w}$

If you do the difference of those two terms, you'll find the first formula.